# How to receive inbound sms on sinch?

Tags: sinch

I am new to Sinch and I wanted to receive sms from users rather then sending an outbound sms at first. I would like to know if it is possible to do so with Sinch?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, rent a number in the dashboard (Sinch.com/dashboard) go to your apps properties and assign the number and configure your callback url.

Then implement this method in your callback URL https://www.sinch.com/docs/sms/#incomingsms

Comment: Ok Thanks. But just one more question (it may sound a bit silly but) How should i retrieve the payload in a Java servlet. I mean if i do a request.getParameter("_WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE"); ???

Comment: And i also tried contacting sinch support for an Indian number but to no avail could you let me know details about the same. You can mail me at register@thakare.xyz

Comment: Hi, its not a silly question, we post a json body, so you should serialize the content to to an object.

Comment: I know that you post a json body. But under what parameter name is it being send to the caller API? I am using Java servlets so i need to know the parameter name to retrieve the JSON body.

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with Javaservlets, but its not a parameter at all, its a post body I think you should do something like this >   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
    String str;
    while( (str = br.readLine()) != null ){
        sb.append(str);
    }    
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());